# how to pass image from one screen to other after picking it from camera/gallery and show in second screen automatically as navigate to second screen

Tags: iphone, flutter, logic, coding-style

how to pass image from one screen to other after picking it from camera or gallery and show in second screen automatically when i navigate  to second screen. Basically i want a method in second screen which runs automatically when i pick image from camera or gallery and navigate to second screen.
This is code for picking image from gallery and navigate to second screen

```
Future<void> predictImagePickerGallery(BuildContext context) async {
    final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) return;
    setState(() {
      _busy = true;
      _image = image;
    });
    if (image != null) {
      print(image.path);
      await navigator.push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              Test2(
                  _image
              ),
        ),
      );

    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
   // recognizeImage(image);
  }
```

Now how can i show this image in second screen automatically as i navigate.

Comment: just collect the image as a file, and pass it with the navigatior to the respective page, In the next page use FileImage and pass the file property from the previous screen

Comment: it works thank you